# compute percentile by group and then add to existing data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
univ  date        ms
A     11/01/2007  0.2
A     11/02/2007  0.3
B     11/01/2007  0.4
B     11/01/2007  0.5
```

What I am trying to do is to compute the percentile by univ and then add to existing data frame the value by each univ as an extra column ms_perc_rank

I am able to compute the percentile by univ by doing this

```
df.groupby('univ')['ms'].quantile(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, use `transform` to assign `groupby` results to your original dataframe:

```
df['ms_perc_rank'] = df.groupby('univ')['ms'].transform('quantile', 0.2)
```

The resulting output:

```
  univ        date   ms  ms_perc_rank
0    A  11/01/2007  0.2          0.22
1    A  11/02/2007  0.3          0.22
2    B  11/01/2007  0.4          0.42
3    B  11/01/2007  0.5          0.42
```